# Ruby elegant way to provide default array values for version string

Tags: arrays, ruby, default-value

This is a trivial question, unsure if I should really be asking here, but would like to see if anyone has a more elegant way to write this in ruby.

I have a version string of format `x.y.z` or `x.y` or `x`. I would like a simple elegant way to convert this into an array where default 0 value is inserted if segment is missing. I have a few different ways to do this, but I was hoping for something a bit cleaner. Atm my current solution is this

```rb
version_string.split('.').each_with_index.with_object(['0','0','0']) { |(segment, i), version_array| version_array[i] = segment }
```

Seems to work fine, and I can always move to a simple method call to make code look cleanup, but something about the use of `each_with_index` and `with_object kinda bugs me. Just curious to see if rest of Ruby community have anything to add

Comment: I don't really feel like this is particularly elegant but you can use a regex to parse "1", "1.2", "1.2.3" into 3-item lists where missing numbers will be nil. `/(\d)(?:\.(\d))?(?:\.(\d))?/.match(string)[1..-1]` e.g. for `string="1.2"` it would return `[1,2,nil]`. Then you could do `map { |num| num || 0 }` on the result before joining. I wish there was a way to do like `ljust` for arrays but I'm not seeing anything.

Comment: Why don't you use a gem like [versionomy](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/versionomy)?

Comment: `/(\d+).?(\d+)?.?(\d+)?/.match(str).captures.map {|s| s.to_i.to_s}` would work. @maxpleaner you could simulate the concept in 2 steps `str.scan(/\d+/).concat(['0','0','0']).first(3)` or `['0','0','0'].unshift(*str.scan(/\d+/)).first(3)`

Comment: The golfiest thing I can come up with is `str.split(?.).+([?0]*3)[..2]` but this assumes the "0"(s) will not be muated later

Answer (score 7):

How about (min Ruby 2.6)

```
version_string.split('.').then { |x, y = '0', z = '0'| [x,y,z] }
```